# Getting Android Advertising ID via Kotlin Programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am rather new to android development and am trying to get the Advertising ID for a particular device.  I've found some stack overflow suggestions on how to do so:

```
val adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext())
val adId = adInfo?.id
```

in a worker thread).  However this keeps on giving me the "Timed out waiting for the service connection" error.

Others seems to have suggest adding the following gradle dependencies help, but not for me:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifiers:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
```

as well as having

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What am I missing to properly get the Advertising ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Rxjava to get aid, you can use Asyntask, coroutine...

1. RxJava

   ```
   fun getAdId() {
       Observable.fromCallable { AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(this).id }
           .subscribeOn(AppScheduler().backgroundThread())
           .observeOn(AppScheduler().mainThread())
           .subscribe(Consumer<String> {
                val adId = it
            }, Consumer<Throwable> {
                // nothing
            })
   }
   ```

- Import Rxjava in app/build.gradle:

  implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

  implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

2. With coroutine of Kotlin:

   ```
   GlobalScope.launch {
       val adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(applicationContext)
       Log.d("text", adInfo.id ?: "unknown")
   }
   ```

Comment: In the second example - coroutune of Kotlin, .getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext() is flagged with warning as: “inappropriate blocking method call” and this is not good because we are loosing the benefits of coroutines and downgrade to one job per thread again. How to avoid this?

Comment: Found a way, just add GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {...} and everything is fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Man thank you so much! Like how you prepared it for copy-paste :)

Comment: After implementing im getting null. Why is that? Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

If someone wonder (like me) why they get

```
 "Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock"
```

when trying to read it from using `viewModelScope` and a suspend function. Here is what you need to do:

Since `viewModelScope` uses `Dispatchers.Main` by default you need it will throw this error.

**Option 1:**

Pass context when launched

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
  // call your suspend function from here
}
```

but in this way you need to do some work when you want to do some work on main thread.

---

**Option 2 (I prefer this):**

use CoroutineContext in your `suspend` function

```kotlin
 suspend fun getAdId(): String? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                try {
                    AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context).id
                } catch (exception: Exception) {
                    null // there still can be an exception for other reasons but not for thread issue
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
fun getAdvertisingId(context: Context, callback: (advertisingId: String?) -> Unit) {
        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                val info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context)
                val id = info.id
                callback(id)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                callback(null)
            }
        }).start()
    }
```